# Import SIM card contacts not working? (HTC One X)

Tags: sim-card, htc-one-x, import

I have a new HTC One X. After storing all my contacts from my previous dumb-phone onto the SIM card, I tried to import them on the new smart-phone. (People->Menu->Import/eexport->Import from SIM) It says "No contacts on your SIM card". But I can see them there if I put it back in my old phone.

I don't think they are stored on my old phone itself, because for each contact it says "Stored to: SIM". Also this (brand new) SIM card is supposed to come pre-loaded with numbers for calling my phone company's customer service, voicemail, etc. so there should be SOMETHING on the SIM.

I am very new to Android and smartphones in general. Help?

Comment: Yes, I did try that, but it didn't work. As I already stated in my question.

Comment: Alternative: Do you have your old phone still? SonyEricsson phones for example can export in .vcf format to the memory card which you can then either import directly on your phone or via gmail.com. You could also send your whole address book at once via bluetooth. there's also software like MobileMaster that handles many brands.

Comment: I do still have it, but my old phone is so prehistorically old I don't think it can do that. That is, it doesn't have Bluetooth nor a memory card. I don't see the model number on the compatibility list for MobileMaster.
I broke down and manually copied all the data across (a glorious waste of two hours) but am still interested in the correct solution.